# How to make a Fortran Makefiles with object files (.o) and a shared library (.so)?

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries, executable, gfortran

I am totally new to the world of Makefiles. I tried to follow some tutorials to make my own makefile. In the examples that I found there was no treatment for a case including object files (.o) and shared libraries (.so). So, I tried to inspire but it seems that there is something missing in my understanding of how to make a Fortran makefile.

I started with a simple example corresponding to the command that I generally use on the terminal:

```
gfortran -ffree-line-length-none -o binary A.F90 B.F90 C.F90 /Path/to/Directory/D.so
```

The command mentioned above works perfectly and lead to the creation of the executable called binary.

The corresponding Makefile that I wrote is:

```
FORTRAN_COMPILER=gfortran
#FORTRAN_FLAGS=-O3 -Wall -Wextra -std=f2008 -ffree-line-length-none
FORTRAN_FLAGS=-ffree-line-length-none
SRC=A.F90 B.F90 C.F90
OBJ1:${SRC:.F90=.o}
SharedLib_PATH = /Path/to/Directory
OBJ2 = $(SharedLib_PATH)/D.so
LIBS     = $(OBJ1) $(OBJ2) 


%.o: %.F90
    @echo 'converting .F90 files to .o'
    $(FORTRAN_COMPILER) $(FORTRAN_FLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

binary: $(LIBS)
    @echo 'make an executable from objet files (.o) and the shared object (.so)'
    $(FORTRAN_COMPILER) $(FORTRAN_FLAGS) -o $@ $(LIBS)

clean:  
    @echo 'clean'
    @rm -f *.mod *.o binary
```

By executing the Makefile, I have:

```
converting .F90 files to .o
gfortran -ffree-line-length-none -o A.o -c A.F90
converting .F90 files to .o
gfortran -ffree-line-length-none -o B.o -c B.F90
converting .F90 files to .o
gfortran -ffree-line-length-none -o C.o -c C.F90
```

And it does not go further and does not generate the executable binary.
Typing again on terminal "make" leads to: `make: Nothing to be done for 'OBJ1'.`
Could you please tell me where the problem comes from? and apologies if the problem is too obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is not right:

```
OBJ1:${SRC:.F90=.o}
```

This defines a *rule* with a *target* named `OBJ1`.  I assume you wanted to define a *variable* named `OBJ1`.  You should write:

```
OBJ1 = $(SRC:.F90=.o)
```

Second, it's important to understand that by default, unless you give it a command line argument specifying otherwise, `make` will try to build the *FIRST* explicit target defined in the makefile.  Due to the above typo the first explicit target is `OBJ1` so that's all it tries to build.

If you want make to build `binary` when you run it with no arguments, make sure that's the first explicit target in your makefile.

Comment: Thank you. By correcting that, the program runs and builds the binary.

Comment: Just one final question: why the "clean" part of the makefile is not executed?

Comment: See my "Second" point above.  Only the first target, and the prerequisites of the first target, are built if you run `make` with no arguments.  If you want some other target to be run, list it on the command line.  For example, `make clean` will build the `clean` target (and not the `binary` target).