# Fortran error: (.text+0x0): multiple definition of

Tags: makefile, module, configure, autotools

I tried to include my Fortran modules in an extensive library that is also written in Fortran. To compile and install this library, the autotools suits are used. I made a `Makefile` to compile separately (in another directory and [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74893823/how-to-make-a-fortran-makefiles-with-object-files-o-and-a-shared-library-so/74893878?noredirect=1#comment132170028_74893878)) my modules and check if they were running fine. The test was successful. However, when I tried to couple them with this extensive library, I had trouble. I think, but not sure, that the problem is coming from the fact that in some of my subroutines, another subroutine is called several times. I have an error as follows:

```
DirectoryA/.libs/A.o: In function `__A_MOD_sub1':
A.F90:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__A_MOD_sub1'
DirectoryA/.libs/A.o:A.F90:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

I tried to couple a very simple module with this library to make sure that the problem is not coming from how I modified the makefiles. This test was successful. In that simple module, I made just some subroutines printing some parameters.

In the new slightly complicated set of modules, I knowingly call a subroutine several times inside of another subroutine to perform a desired task. Is that where the problem comes from? Shall I add a flag to `configure.ac` in order to circumvent this issue?

Comment: A multiple definition error indicates that you the linker sees multiple functions with the same name (`__A_MOD_sub1`) among the objects being linked.  It is likely that these are identical, but that is not certain, so you really need find a *bona fide* solution.  You haven't given us enough information to answer with any specificity, but probably you are linking multiple libraries and / or object files containing the function in question into the same executable.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I added `LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition"` to the configure.ac file and the problem is solved.

Comment: That may have made the compiler stop complaining, but it is the wrong solution.